# Programatically Toggle Free / Busy Event Status for Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have created a calendar system that loads all events from a calendar using Google Calendar API in Javascript, and figures out if the event or free or busy by loading that JSON object.

I want to be able to programmatically, through Javascript preferably, through a link allow someone to click a link to accept the event (I have the event id, calendarId, etc) via email or on a landing page, and the Free/Busy Status will be toggled to Busy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Freebusy: query](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query). It returns free/busy information for a set of calendars.

> **Free/busy** — A time when a calendar has events scheduled is considered "busy", a time when a calendar has no events is considered "free". The Freebusy resource allows querying for the set of busy times for a given calendar or set of calendars.

Try to look at this [link](https://github.com/timohtey/FreeBusy). This might help.

Comment: For the user to accept the event, I think you have to query the attendees calendar events by authorizing it and then match the ID of the events with the ID of the event which was generated. You can also use calendar API to accept calendar invite. In `events.update`, you can set the parameter value, `attendees[].responseStatus` to "accepted". Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update).